# How to re-render child component when Parent state is changed?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have Parent component which include child component aswell. I pass some props to child component from parent. My problem is when i change slider to get new value on parent component, re render does not work on Parent. this causes not re render child component as well.

when changing slider, the function get executed and state is changed with new value. But this setstate is not trigger rerender. I am debugging the below code, console logs are like this(changing slider to 1 from 0);

```
delay -> 0
delay timetypes -> 0  (6 times executed)
delay -> 1
```

and when i touch one of the touchable opacities,gets this.state.delay = 0
but i changed 0 to 1 via slider.

```
// welcome.js

export default class welcome extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      GridViewItems: [
        { key: "1 min game", min: 1, sec: 0 },
        { key: "3 min game", min: 3, sec: 0 },
        { key: "5 min game", min: 5, sec: 0 },
        { key: "7 min game", min: 7, sec: 0 },
        { key: "10 min game", min: 10, sec: 0 },
        { key: "15 min game", min: 15, sec: 0 }
      ],
      value : 0
    };
  }

  GetGridViewItem(item) {
    Alert.alert(item);
  }

  change(value) {
    console.log("change value -> " + value );
    this.setState({
      value: value
  })}

  render() {
    console.log("delay -> " + this.state.value);
    return (

      <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.welcomeText}>Welcome ChessClock</Text>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Delay Time: {this.state.value}</Text>
        <Slider
          style = {styles.slider}
          step={1}
          maximumValue={20}
          value={this.state.value}
          onValueChange={(val)=> this.setState({value: val})}
        />
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.GridViewItems}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <TimerTypes
              navigation={this.props.navigation}
              BlockStyle={styles.GridViewBlockStyle}
              TextStyle={styles.GridViewInsideTextItemStyle}
              title={item.key}
              time={item.min * 60 + item.sec}
              delay = {this.state.value}
            />
          )}
          numColumns={2}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    flex: 1,
    margin: 10,
    paddingTop: Platform.OS === "ios" ? 20 : 0
  },
  GridViewBlockStyle: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    height: 100,
    margin: 5,
    backgroundColor: "#05BC87"
  },
  GridViewInsideTextItemStyle: {
    color: "#fff",
    padding: 10,
    fontSize: 18,
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  welcomeText: {
    color: "#0F2284",
    padding: 60,
    fontSize: 30,
    justifyContent: "center",
    textAlign: "center"
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 20,
    justifyContent: "center",
    marginLeft:10
  },
  slider: {
    width: '100%',
    marginBottom: 25,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems : "center"
  }
});



// timeTypes

export default class timeTypes extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            delay : props.delay
        }
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({ delay: nextProps.delay });  
      }

    render() {
        console.log("delay timetypes -> " + this.props.delay);
        console.log("delay timetypes -> " + this.state.delay);
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home', {
                time: this.props.time,
                delay : this.state.delay
            })}
            style={this.props.BlockStyle} >
                <Text style={this.props.TextStyle}>
                    {this.props.title}
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity >
        );
    }
}
```

The happy path should be when changing slider to get new number, parent will rerender and child should get the new value.

github repo: https://github.com/Erkanerkisi/ChessClock

Comment: Have you tried adding `extraData={ this.state.value }` to your FlatList component ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs:

> FlatList is a PureComponent which means that it will not re-render if
>   props remain shallow-equal. Make sure that everything your renderItem
>   function depends on is passed as a prop (e.g. extraData) that is not
>   === after updates, otherwise your UI may not update on changes. This includes the data prop and parent component state.

So try adding `extraData={ this.state.value }` to your FlatList component

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Now I got the problem. Actually there is no problem with component but the same props cause no render child.

Comment: I'm I didn't get the issue ... when you're passing the same props to your TimeTypes component ... the expected behavior is not to re-render the component

Comment: I ve been giving different value to timetypes as you can see. But time types is in flatlist and i did not give any change to flatlist. As a result flatlist does not see any changes and not render itself and childs.

Comment: Your TimeTypes component does not re-render even after passing `extraData={ this.state.value }` to your FlatList ?? ... after you add your extraData field to your FlatList... your TimeTypes component should re-render when your `value` piece of state changes

Comment: If it didn't work ... try this `extraData={ this.state }`